# How to pipe on a condition in Bash

Tags: bash, scripting, pipe

I'm over-complicating the problem, but is there a way of piping a command into another, given a condition on one-line in Bash?

Basically I currently have this

```
if [ "$check" -eq 1 ]; then
    echo -n "foo" | xclip -selection clipboard
else
    echo -n "foo"
fi
```

I'm wondering is there anyway in Bash to turn this into something that looks like:

```
echo -n "foo" && [ "$check" -eq 1 ] | xclip -selection clipboard
```

Where if $check == 1, "foo" will be piped into the clipboard, else the contents will be output into stdout and the pipe never activates and nothing is written into the clipboard. I want this to be a one-liner where I only call echo once.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$ check=0
$ echo "foo" | { if (( check == 1 )); then cat -n; else cat -; fi; }
foo

$ check=1
$ echo "foo" | { if (( check == 1 )); then cat -n; else cat -; fi; }
     1  foo
```

Comment: This works perfectly if the ```cat -n``` is changed to the clipboard. Thanks a million Ed.

Comment: You're welcome. Whether the command in question is `clipboard` or `cat -n` or some other command that takes piped input doesn't matter to the problem of how to conditionally pipe to a command and not everyone has `clipboard` on their system so using `cat -n` for the example is much more useful in general to readers of this forum than using `clipboard` since everyone can just copy/paste my answer to try it.

Answer (score 1):

You are not so far away.

You can pipe your output of `echo` to a sub-shell

```sh
echo -n "foo" | ([[ "$check" -eq 1 ]] && xclip -selection clipboard || cat - )
```

In this code, your `echo` will be used as input by either `xclip` or `cat` based on the condition.

**Edit:**

If you also want the command to fail if `xclip` fails, you can do the following:

```sh
echo -n "foo" | ( ( [[ "$check" -ne 1 ]] && cat - ) || ( [[ "$check" -eq 1 ]] && xclip -selection clipboard ) )
```

But that way may be less readable than your multiline code.

A multiline solution with only one `echo` can be:

```sh
# Create temporary pipe file
PIPE=$(mktemp -u)
mkfifo $PIPE
# Open pipe handles
# 6 can be replaced by any other non-opened fd identifier
exec 6<>$PIPE
# Remove file from disk
rm $PIPE
echo -n "foo" >&6
if [[ "$check" -eq 1 ]]; then
    xclip -selection clipboard <&6
else
    cat - <&6
fi
# Close file handles
exec 6<&- 6>&-
```

Comment: That doesn't mean what it looks like it means, it's not a ternary expression it's just left-to-right evaluation of success/fail exit status of the last command to run. If `$check` is `1` and `xclip` fails (or can't be found) then `cat` will be called.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, although as mentioned by Ed, I would ideally like this to fail if xclip is not found or fails. If you can fix that I would happily give you the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a special var (maybe `check`, I will use `cmd`) for your optional command (example with uppercase):

```
# default
cmd='cat -'
echo "foo" | $cmd
# output: foo
cmd='tr [:lower:] [:upper:]'
echo "foo" | $cmd
# output FOO
```

When you want this construction with a changing value of `check`, you can use a function:

```
xcmd() {
   sed '/0/ s/.*/cat -/; /1/ s/.*/tr [:lower:] [:upper:]/' <<< "${check-0}"
}
```

or with `xclip`:

```
xcmd() {
   sed '/0/ s/.*/cat -/; /1/ s/.*/xclip -selection clipboard/' <<< "${check-0}"
}
```

and now:

```
check=0
echo "foo" | $(xcmd)
# output: foo
check=1
echo "foo" | $(xcmd)
# output: FOO or the xclip pipe
```

Answer (score 0):

A conditionally defined function may be more appropriate in some case, such as if `check` is checked a lot. This also assumes that `check`'s value won't change between uses of `receiver`.

```
if (( check == 1 )); then
    receiver () {
        xclip -selection clipboard
    }
else
    receiver () {
        cat -n
    }
fi

printf 'foo' | receiver
```